# Meaning of "put off by the claim"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

What is Meaning of the phrase verb "put off by the claim". In which situation we use this phrase verb. Please make an example to clarify what does it mean.

I would greatly appreciate for any suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! You are expected to provide [more details](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please), like an actual example sentence and any research you have done to answer your own question. Questions that can be easily answered by a dictionary or quick google search are [off-topic](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I suspect you will want to consult this dictionary entry: [put off](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/put+off).

Comment: @Max thank you for your notification. I will try to ask question based on the principles of ELL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Put off* is a phrasal verb that means "to be offended" or "to lose enthusiasm."

If a claim has caused someone to be offended or lose enthusiasm, then you can say "He/she was put off by the claim."

Comment: I appreciate for your useful answer.